# Android 4.2 SharedPreferences returns wrong value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get some values from SharedPreferences, and I write it in this code;

```
            SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt(MainActivity.OBSDONE, observationer);
            editor.putInt(MainActivity.COROBS, korrekte);
            editor.commit();
```

I got the data from the SharedPreferences-file by pulling it off the Virtual Device, and the data looks correct.

When I try to pull it out from SharedPreferences with;

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int obs = prefs.getInt(OBSDONE,0);
    int cor = prefs.getInt(COROBS,0);
```

it returns 0 to both values?

Comment: I got this data from the Virtual Device; <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<map>

<int value="3" name="OBSDONE"/>

<int value="2" name="COROBS"/>

</map>

Comment: Put that data in the question not the comments. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Do you use second block of the code in the another activity?

Comment: hi @Hans-HenrikHøgsted Try to declare your preference like this 
SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

Comment: I assume both calls are not made from the same activity?

Comment: the calls were made from separate activities, yes, and Sheychan's answer worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
prefs.edit().putInt(MainActivity.OBSDONE,observationer).apply();
prefs.edit().putInt(MainActivity.COROBS, korrekte).apply();
```

Comment: getBaseContext is not available from any activity

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Or if u only have a context:

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
```